# how to use regex if I am looking for a specific word in entire string

Tags: python, regex

My output is

```
Select action => test: username, status 1
```

I am trying to do *if 'username' string exists, then proceed to code otherwise print fail and exit*

if I write `p.expect('*username*')` it returns error

```
raise error, v # invalid expression
sre_constants.error: nothing to repeat
```

which is known bug in python I guess.

In this case, what is the best way?

Comment: If you do not need a whole word search, use the one in the answer below.

Comment: I use https://regex101.com/ to help me learn about and write regex code.

Comment: Checking if _username_ exists will be tricky. It could have variations in spelling and alignment and could actually be a color, i.e. John Brown's big day. You'd totally miss that. The big thing is case, and whether first or last or both. It's akin to parsing language, and that's not possible with regular expressions.

Comment: If you do need a regex, you need to use escaping method to find literals. `p.expect(re.escape(userstring))`

Answer (score 2):

Why use a regex for this? If you're just seeing if the substring is in a string just use

```
if `username` in some_string:
    #exec more code.
```

Comment: the thing is I am running python script and sending commands to my device. It creates log file on the device and I am trying to see if username exists in that log file. hence can't use if username in log.txt

Comment: You can. `if username in [x.strip() for x in open("log.txt", "r").readlines()]` Although you probably don't want to open the file like this and you can adjust to fit needs. Just a random example to fit in the comment

Answer (score 0):

If you are intent on using RegEx for some reason:

```
import re
output = "Select action => test: username, status 1"

UserNameRegEx = re.search('username',output) #RegEx to search for the string "username" in string "output". Stores as an object.

#if regEx object UserNameRegEx exists (meaning that a match was found)
if match_module_present:        
    username = UserNameRegEx.group(1) #assigns the matched string from regex object to a string variable
    #run more code
```

Comment: This might be fisible if I know the output string. In my case, I am doing some user activity on my device and trying to read console output. Python script is invoked from my pc and device is unix based